# Repository history in log files

Tags: java, svn, repository, history

there is a little project for me to make a java app which analyzes yours SVN repository files (history), in other words, you need to make a project. using this app you should get the history of changes made to a repository.

tried some examples 
(f.e. http://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit/branches/sgk/doc/examples/src/org/tmatesoft/svn/examples/repository/History.java ) 
 and only get error : "... cannot be resolved".

Comment: You need to post some code, otherwise people will not be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/io/SVNRepository.html

i even can't import those libraries. svnkit already installed.